# Can display issues affect SEO?

Tags: web-development, html, css, seo

Can website display issues on certain platforms affect a website's search rankings and potentially hinder any SEO efforts?

Comment: Please edit out the irrelevant back story, bit hard to locate the actual question.

Comment: It's always a tough call with the Stack Exchange sites. If I ask a 1-paragraph question that doesn't explain the backdrop, I often get closevotes on the grounds that people claim I'm not showing enough research. If I go too far the other way then (as in your case) I irritate some people because I've been too verbose. How about this: once someone answer the question sufficiently, I'll go back and edit it down to a 1-paragraph question to reduce clutter and free up a little server space. Savvy?

Comment: Probably more appropriate for webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: @herpylderp What your family thinks you do is not "showing enough research" ;)

Comment: I see this has been edited down to a 1-sentence question. If this is what the community wants, then so be it, but please do not downvote or closevote this question because it is: too vague, doesn't show any research, etc. That would be a double standard.

Comment: @herpylderp: Reading over the backstory, most of it fails to show research.  Showing research would be, "I read Google's webmaster guidelines and they say X, Y, and Z about website display issues."  Your back story is largely irrelevant to the question, with the possible exception of "an SEO expert told me that website display issues should be fixed before performing SEO." On the other hand, for example, "I am doing web development for my father" is not relevant.

Comment: That's exactly the point that @Anonymous made when he/she edited my post. The community has already spoken: my backstory was irrelevant. I'm just asking that no one downvote/closevote this *because* of the way the post was edited. If I submit version 1.0 of something, and it is found lacking, and someone else comes along and edits it to make version 2.0, and then someone penalizes (closevote, etc.) it because of the content in version 2.0, that's not my fault. That's someone else edit.

Comment: @herpylderp - I feel your pain, I've been penalized or had criticisms aimed at me before, for edits that others have made to my questions. It's frustrating, I just thought it better to try and keep your question open for you by formatting it as a concise, clear question.

Comment: @Anonymous - I appreciate your edit and it was obviously helpful as no one has down/closevoted it or complained since.

Comment: The edit history is amazing.  Nice guess, parser.

Comment: @stevether - Haha...

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that display techniques might cause problems with SEO. I'll go over a few but without more specifics it's hard to say if what you're doing will cause problems or be unimportant.

1. URL - Your URL should include page specific keywords (yoursite.com/brandname-mens-loafers.php). The directory depth shouldn't be excessive, no more than about 3-4 levels at most. Querystring parameters should be avoided as much as possible since this can cause duplicate on-site content and other crawling problems. URL's should be easy for people to copy to share via social media, email, blogs and so forth.
2. Content Layout - Insure meaningful, keyword relevant, content displays above the fold. Avoid using AJAX or other client side script techniques to show primary information although additional info can be shown using this technique. If possible, try to load as much textual content as possible at page load.
3. Mobile - Use a responsive CSS layout rather than a separate subdomain for mobile. This prevents crawling errors, unintended content duplication and so forth. Include address, phone number and other contact info.
4. Page elements - Avoid links to outside sites, especially sitewide footer/sidebar links. Use a clear title and description metatags. These aren't important for ranking but may be used to display info about your page on search engine results, thus improving click-thru. Include widgets for sharing your link via social media and email.

Answer (score -1):

I don’t know what you mean by “*even perform* SEO”

The fact of matter is that if the Site doesn’t render properly on Mobile devices it will affect your position on *Mobile* search results.

That beings said, if by performing SEO you mean she is *editing your HTML*, then yes She is right to ask you to finalize you HTML prior to her changing it (or making change recommendations).

Comment: Thanks @Morons (+1) - a few followups: (1) since I'm fuzzy on what specific list of "to-dos" are involved with optimizing search engine results (SEO), I use the term "perform SEO" to reference them vaguely! But yes, it probably, ultimately, boils down to editing HTML. (2) You are misunderstanding the situation. She is not asking me to finalize the HTML before she changes it (for "performing SEO"), she is saying she **can't** "perform SEO" until I fix the display issues first. Thus she is saying its a barrier for her to even begin working.

Comment: In other words, she claims I need to fix HTML to display right, otherwise it will affect her ability to make SEO work. What I'm asking is this: **if a site doesn't render correctly, will that affect its ability to rank in search engines. If so, why?**

Comment: @herpylderp Because Google cares about the quality of their search results.

Comment: I'm not trying to be difficult here, but how does Google know that an image will display incorrectly when viewed in Safari, or that a div tag won't render properly in IE 7? This just doesn't make sense! **In other words, I doubt very highly that the way a HTML page actually renders (visually) to an end user is something Google can calculate and take into consideration for PageRank (or whatever it uses).** Are you sure you're understanding my question? Thanks again for all the help so far.

Comment: @herpylderp - For the most part Google won't know. Minor discrepencies (or even fairly major ones) will go unnoticed by search engines. They will see the content and not much more. However, search engines are wise to black-hat SEO techniques like placing a large white div over spammy, keyword-stuffed paragraphs and similar practises. Basically, you've no need to be worried if you or your SEO contact aren't trying to 'cheat' the system.

Comment: Thanks @Anonymous (+1) - so, as far as you know, the SEO specialist's claims aren't correct, yes? Again, she is claiming that there's no way for her to do her job and get the site to rank well until the display issues are resolved. I'm saying that he claim is bologna, and that although the display issues definitely need to be remedied at some point, there's nothing display-related that would affect her ability to perform SEO services. Can you confirm? Thanks again for all your help so far!

Comment: @herpylderp - I'd feel comfortable saying that a skew-whiff version of your site being displayed to mobile devices should not affect SEO in any way, unless you're trying to target those devices (which you probably should be, how much trouble would it be for you to write a seperate stylesheet for mobile-friendly resolutions?). I'd say find a new SEO 'specialist'. :-) Or better still look into it a bit yourself, it really isn't as complicated as the 'specialists' and 'professionals' would have you believe. I bet you could be up to scratch with the basics and more easily within a day.

Comment: Here is a good starter's guide: http://www.seomoz.org/beginners-guide-to-seo and one of the most-cited books on SEO can be found here: http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Art-Theory-Practice-OReilly/dp/0596518862

Comment: Screen Rendering is a factor in Mobile SEO. Google for Details.

Comment: As far as knowing if its holding her back from doing whatever it is she claims to be doing.. We cant tell you that unless you tell us exactly what she will be doing

Comment: @herpylderp - Google recently introduced a Chrome based web crawler that inteprets the content of a page visually as well as executing more scripts. Google has done a lot with visual data and this is an extension of it. So, how your site looks in Chrome and Chrome Mobile is important.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, When the website's display isn't proper on different platforms, for example, it looks different on different devices, then it's user experience will be hindered.
For any search engine website, when its user experience is hindered,  then they do not allow such websites to rank higher on their platforms.